# How do spectrums interact with bi-Lipschitz maps?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations, special-functions

If it makes things simple, we can just stick to bi-Lipschitz maps from $S^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ (w.r.t geodesic distance on the sphere with the standard round metric and the $2-$norm on the Euclidean space in the target) or bi-Lipschitz maps from $\mathbb{R}^{k+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ (and look at their restrictions to $S^k$ which I believe are still bi-Lipschitz but with different constants w.r.t the metric pulled back from $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$).

In any of these scenarios I would like to know if there is a way to transfer spectral data (like eigenvalues and their multiplicities) of some integral operator or the Laplacian on the domain sphere to the ``same" operator defined on the image of the sphere.

---

If there are no nice relations like this  w.r.t bi-Lipschitz maps, I would be equally happy to know if there are other classes of maps through which spectral data can be nicely transferred. Because these operators like the Laplacian are built from the metric, I am hoping that mappings like the bi-Lipschitz ones which approximately preserve the geodesic distances might help in doing such a transfer.